# Is it possible to enter data into a JQuery mobile site that is in an iframe on Safari using an iPad?

Tags: ipad, iframe, jquery-mobile, mobile-safari

I am attempting to enable iPad Safari users to use our JQuery mobile application through an iFrame - http://dev.eventhello.com/overridden_routes/not_mobile. For some reason, the buttons are not clickable and the text fields are not enterable. The site is fully functional on the iPad when not accessed through an iFrame - http://dev.eventhello.com/users/login.

Comment: Just to make sure, the iPad isn’t on iOS 5 beta, is it? iOS 5 beta 2 seems to have problems with some input elements at times.

Comment: I second @Alan H.'s comment - seems to work OK on an iPad running 4.3.3

Comment: I just redirect the iPad to the mobile version of the site (http://dev.eventhello.com/users/login) rather than trying to render the page with the mobile site embedded in an iFrame (http://dev.eventhello.com/overridden_routes/not_mobile) for the time being. I don't believe it is an iOS 5 beta issue. It seems to happen on all iPads.

Answer (score 0):

Given the above discussion, it seems like this may be an iOS 5 beta 2-related bug.  It should clear up before iOS 5 goes stable.  Further discussion on this issue should use Apple’s developer forums, per NDA.

Comment: This is not just an i0S 5 beta 2-related bug. It seems to be happening on all versions. I had the iframe scaled down before using css but now it is full size and is still behaving the same way.

Comment: But we've just told you it's **not** happening for our non-iOS5 devices, so why do you think it is? I'm confused.

Comment: My mistake - I said it wasn't working still because the CSS scaled down version was still cached on the test device. I have removed the CSS scaling of the iFrame and it can now be interacted with.